# Compiler error when applying theme with databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-theme, android-styles, android-binding-adapter

My code shuffles colors and indexes for a list of `ColorBox` objects indefinitely.
This is my view:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/App.WidgetStyle.ColorBox"
    android:text="@{item.id}"
    android:theme="@{item.theme}"
    tools:text="A"
    tools:theme="@style/App.ColorBox" />
```

My styles:

```
<style name="App.WidgetStyle.ColorBox" parent="App">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/square_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/square_size</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_for_rounded_outlined_bg</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans_bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

My custom background shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="?attr/backgroundShapeCornerRadius" />
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/colorSecondary"/>
</shape>
```

My themes:

```
<style name="App.ColorBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="backgroundShapeCornerRadius">0dp</item>
</style>
<style name="App.ColorBox.Red">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_1</item>
</style>
<style name="App.ColorBox.Green">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_2</item>
</style>
<style name="App.ColorBox.White">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_3</item>
</style>
<style name="App.ColorBox.Blue">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_4</item>
</style>
```

My data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class ColorBox(var id: String, @StyleRes var theme: Int) : Parcelable
```

And if I try to compile, the compiler hates it:

> > Task :app:kaptDevDebugKotlin ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR
> >     Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the
> >     current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code
> >     generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR
> >     Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the
> >     current runtime version
> >     4.7.1/Users/.../DataBinderMapperImpl.java:10:
> >     error: cannot find symbol import
> >     com....RowForItemBindingImpl;
> >            ^   symbol:   class RowForItemBindingImpl
> >
> > Task :app:kaptDevDebugKotlin FAILED   location: package com....databinding FAILURE: Build
> >     failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevDebugKotlin'.
>
>   > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
>   >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

But if I create a `BindingAdapter` (for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865124/1423773) didn't work)

```
object AppBindingAdapters {

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["colorBoxTheme"])
    fun colorBoxTheme(view: View, @StyleRes themeResId: Int) {
        view.background = ResourcesProvider(view.context).drawable(R.drawable.shape_for_rounded_outlined_bg, themeResId)
    }
}

<TextView
    style="@style/App.WidgetStyle.ColorBox"
    android:text="@{item.id}"
    app:colorBoxTheme="@{item.theme}"
    tools:text="A"
    tools:theme="@style/App.ColorBox.Green" />
```

It works :)

[image]

Is this a `databinding` bug or the desired behaviour? Why can't I apply a theme dynamically with `databinding` without the `BindingAdapter` "hack"?

Btw, [ResourcesProvider](https://github.com/GuilhE/ResourcesProvider-ktx) it's a very handy helper class to provide resources.

Comment: Yep. It is a databinding thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yb...@google.com  #3Apr 30, 2020 16:45 Status: Won't
>   Fix (Infeasible) 16:45
>   +CC:​yb...@google.com 16:45
>
> you cannot apply themes via data binding unfortunately. they are only
>   ever read on inflation time and useless afterwards (we don't have a
>   working setStheme function on views). nothing we can do on the data
>   binding side unfortunately.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152712592